# Batch script using 7 zip

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the below folder structure, I want to zip all the files and folders within the folder.

```
Master Directory
File 1
File 2

SubFolder1
ABC Folder
file 1
XYZ Folder
file 1
```

And I'm using the below code, when I run it I am able to **zip** sub folders in the master directory and their sub folder and files. But not able to zip files inside the master directory.

```
CD /d D:\reports
for /d %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  "D:\Report.zip" "%%X"
```

How to zip all the contents in the master folder. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So the `Master Directory` is `D:\reports\`, right?

Comment: `for /D %%X in (. *) do ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "D:\Report.zip" "D:\reports\"
```

It will compress all files and subfolders inside `D:\reports\` into `D:\Report.zip`.

If you don't want the top `reports` folder inside the zip but just the subfiles and subfolders, use this:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "D:\Report.zip" "D:\reports\*"
```

Comment: IMO both variants will include `reports`, to avoid that make reports your current dir and use just `*` to select files/folders.

Comment: You are right, I tried also, but with a relative path and that seems to make the difference.